# Hiding items in highchart legend

Tags: php, wordpress, highcharts

I have a highchart displaying fuel types. I would like to hide certain fuel types based on a users profile. The if statement is an example as its the JS I can't get to work. I want this to hide the legend for the series named CNG but nothing happens. Where am I going wrong?

```
if( user profile does not include fuel type CNG ) : ?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({

            series: [{
                name: ['CNG'],
                showInLegend: false
            }]        
        });    
    });
</script>
<?php endif;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide the series from the legend when the chart is initialized, it is as you have written:

```
series: {
  showInLegend: false,
  ...
}
```

If you want to hide a series from the legend after the chart has been initialized, you have to use either [`chart.update`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update) or [`chart.series[index].update`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update) where chart is the variable containing your highchart object. Like this:

```
chart.series[0].update({
    showInLegend: false
  }, true, false);
```

This will hide the first serie's legend.

```js
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        showEmpty: false
    },

    yAxis: {
        showEmpty: false
    },

    series: [{
     name: 'First series',
        data: [15,41,13,31,104,124,29,55,63,71],
    }, {
     name: 'Second series',
      data: [14,51,123,31,134,123,23,5,6,7]
    }]
});


// Toggle names
let toggle = true;
$('#legend').click(function () {
 if(toggle) {
    chart.series[0].update({
        showInLegend: false
    }, true, false);
    
    toggle = false;
    }
    else {
    chart.series[0].update({
        showInLegend: true
    }, true, false);
    
    toggle = true;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 150px"></div>

<button id="legend">Toggle legend</button>
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/vkdcs79x/

---

Using jQuery to get the highcharts object can be done like this:

```
$('#container').highcharts().series[0].update({
  showInLegend: false
}, true, false);
```

To trigger a update after the chart has loaded this can be used:

```
$('#container').ready(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts().series[0].update({
    showInLegend: false
  }, true, false);
})
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/vkdcs79x/9/

Comment: I'm using a wordpress plugin (wpdatatables) to generate the charts so am guessing the chart is already initialized. I've modified my code to match yours (I think) but it still doesn't work.<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#chart-container').onload(function () {
 
   chart.series[0].update({
        showInLegend: false
    }, true, false);
    
});  
   
</script>

Comment: Some issues though, there is no function called onload in jquery, so I don't know exactly how your onload function works. That said, I don't know if you have assigned your highcharts object to a variable. I updated my answer, to show how you can use jquery to get the highcharts object and update it based on its "readyness".

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I think I am missing something really simple - not very good a coding. When I place the trigger a update after the chart has loaded I get an error Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function. I am placing the jquery in the html / php after the chart code

Comment: jquery needs to be included before any jquery functions can be run, the error you have is saying that jquery is not included on the page when you try to use it. In your `<head>` you need to have `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>`. At this point I am just guessing what might be wrong/missing. I think it would be better if you included some more code in your original question.